# Given a finite non abelian group G, prove the order of the center is less than or equal to 1/4 of the order of the group.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-actions

I am a bit confused on where to start with this one. The question given was

> Let $G$ be a non abelian finite group. Prove $|Z(G)| \leq \frac {1}{4} |G|$.

Am I supposed to use some property of centers or am I just blanking on something really basic

Comment: Think about the quotient $G / Z(G)$.

Comment: This provides another good answer for my question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999247/if-g-zg-is-cyclic-then-g-is-abelian-what-is-the-point.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367184/g-is-a-nonabelian-finite-group-then-zg-leq-frac14g.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Using this approach, $1/4$ is the best bound  you can get of the form $1/n$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227962/a-group-with-order-exactly-4-times-the-order-of-its-center